# Scaling canvas jsplumb/fabric.js

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs, jsplumb

I'm using a javascript library (jsPlumb) which generate me a state machine, with connections, etc.

I'm trying to add a zoom in and out function to the generated graph.

The code generated is something like that:

```
<div id="canvas">
    <canvas style="position: absolute; height: 4px; width: 4px; left: 907.816650390625px; top: 659.816650390625px; " class="_jsPlumb_endpoint  ui-draggable ui-droppable" height="4" width="4"></canvas>
     ...
```

with a lot of canvas elements inside the div wrapper.

So I'm trying to find a library which could allow me to easily scale all these canvas element.

Fabric.js sound good but I didn't find any way to "load" an existing canvas for applying transformation to the canvas itself, but just for applying a transformation to an element inside the canvas.

Does anyone know a library which could do it?
Or if you've ever did something for adding a zoom in/out function to jsplumb, I'd be happy too !
I'd especially like a solution with Fabric.js as this library provides a lot of useful other functions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for zooming the whole canvas then this might interest you...

http://jsfiddle.net/Q3TMA/

```
canvas.setHeight(canvas.getHeight() * SCALE_FACTOR);
canvas.setWidth(canvas.getWidth() * SCALE_FACTOR);
```

I have not created the fiddle.. just found through some searching on random things. Hope that helps

Comment: I'll take a look at this, that seems interesting, Thanks !

Comment: This makes the canvas bigger but does not scale any objects that might be on the canvas.

Answer (score 1):

So, here's the solution I have

```
    function zoomin() {
        zoom += .1;
        zoomIt(1.1);
        $('#zoom_pct').text('%'+Math.round(zoom*100));
    }
    function zoomout() {
        zoom -= .1;
        zoomIt(.9); 
        $('#zoom_pct').text('%'+Math.round(zoom*100));
    }
    function zoomIt(factor) {
        canvas.setHeight(canvas.getHeight() * factor);
        canvas.setWidth(canvas.getWidth() * factor);
        // UPDATE: Scale Background images as well
        if (canvas.backgroundImage) {
            var bi = canvas.backgroundImage;
            bi.width = bi.width * factor; bi.height = bi.height * factor;
        }
// Do we need to scale overlayImage?
        var objects = canvas.getObjects();
        for (var i in objects) {
            var scaleX = objects[i].scaleX;
            var scaleY = objects[i].scaleY;
            var left = objects[i].left;
            var top = objects[i].top;

            var tempScaleX = scaleX * factor;
            var tempScaleY = scaleY * factor;
            var tempLeft = left * factor;
            var tempTop = top * factor;

            objects[i].scaleX = tempScaleX;
            objects[i].scaleY = tempScaleY;
            objects[i].left = tempLeft;
            objects[i].top = tempTop;

            objects[i].setCoords();
        }

        canvas.renderAll();        
    }
```

Comment: As I understand your solution is a compination of the otherr two proposed. Can you please elaborate more, on how you came up with that code and what are the differences / changes from the other 2 solutions? Thank you!

Comment: It's simple. Instead of trying to adjust the viewport, I set the canvas height and width, and then loop over every object on the page and scale it. How it differs from the other two I don't remember 6 months later.

Comment: I get error `objects[i].setCoords is not a function` with this. Any ideas?

Comment: @RickyOdinMatthews are you sure you're getting a Fabric object? setCoords should be a valid method for that object.

Comment: @JasonMaggard thanks for reply. Yeah, for some reason it works if i use the .forEachObject function instead. Probably to do with canvas being re-initiated or something

Answer (score 0):

I wrote small lib which extends fabricjs by zooming and viewport changing: https://github.com/wojtek-krysiak/fabricjs-viewport

Example: http://wojtek-krysiak.github.io/fabricjs-viewport/

Comment: Looking at what you've done... The objects on the canvas scale, but the canvas doesn't.

I've been trying to mix these two approaches, but it still doesn't scale quite the way I'd expect.

    `canvas.setHeight(canvas.getHeight() * 1.1);
    canvas.setWidth(canvas.getWidth() * 1.1);
    canvas.setZoom(canvas.viewport.zoom*1.1);`